# How to use Java 7 HashMaps in Java 8?

Tags: java, hashmap, java-8, upgrade, java-7

I'm in the process of upgrading an application that relies on the Java 7 iteration order of HashMap. The Java 8 HashMap changed its iteration order, which is incompatible with some of this application (probably bad design), I have to use Java 7 HashMaps to successfully migrate the application to Java 8. This is the way I thought of doing it:

1. Make a Java7HashMap that extends the regular Java 8 HashMap
2. Look up the source code of the Java 7 HashMap, copy and paste.
3. Replace the "import java.util.HashMap;" with "import (...).Java7HashMap;"
4. Thoroughly test it all.

Would this be a good way of doing it? It is unfortunately not an option to rewrite the parts that rely on the Java 7 version of the HashMap.

Comment: HashMap is not sorted, so what do you mean by "relies on the Java 7 way of sorting the HashMap"?

Comment: Basically all newer versions of Java is backward compatible with older versions, I feel once you migrate to Java 8, you shouldn't face any issue with Java 7 code.

Comment: @Simze Unless you're relying on undocumented and implementation details, like in this case (which is how a HashMap behaved internally in Java 7).

Comment: Maybe he is talking about this here: http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue235.html ... the point is that the Java8 implementation of HashMaps is in deed different; so something that works nicely with Java7, might give you a headache with Java8 (at runtime, because of very different performance!)

Comment: Probably you need a LinkedHashMap instead? (Check this article about the changes: https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/util/hashmap/hashmap-changes-in-java-8/)

Comment: "It is unfortunately not an option to rewrite the parts that rely on the Java 7 version of the HashMap." Why is that? Seems to me that this is the problem you should solve. Maybe ask a question on workplace.stackexchange.com if you have a problem convincing people of that need.

Comment: You seem to have a strange definition of “to successfully migrate the application to Java 8”. Copying the Java 7 JRE implementation means actually *not* migrating to Java 8…

Comment: "HashMap is not sorted, so what do you mean by "relies on the Java 7 way of sorting the HashMap"?"  
From the article: "Several applications rely in the fact that hash map entries are retrieved in the same order that they were inserted in the map. This was never assured by the java.util.HashMap but some programmers ignored it and built their programs assuming that the iteration order will be historical. Using java 7 entries will be retrieved in the same way that they were inserted (more or less)."
I should have been more clear in my question about this.

Comment: ""It is unfortunately not an option to rewrite the parts that rely on the Java 7 version of the HashMap." Why is that? Seems to me that this is the problem you should solve. Maybe ask a question on workplace.stackexcha‌​nge.com if you have a problem convincing people of that need."
I lied here. It's possible, I can't go into much details here, but it would require a script to be built and to run 24/7 for over 2 months to make all historic data compatible with the Java 8 implementation. I came up with this way, and it was considered a possible solution to this problem.

Comment: "You seem to have a strange definition of “to successfully migrate the application to Java 8”. Copying the Java 7 JRE implementation means actually not migrating to Java 8…"
You are correct here. I suppose I'd be upgrading the application from Java 7 to Java 8.

Comment: @Gamer1120 > "...Using java 7 entries will be retrieved in the same way that they were inserted (more or less)." I should have been more clear in my question about this.
So you need the same order they were inserted? In that case https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html

Comment: @GáborBakos It seems like the application depends on Java 7 HashMap's iteration order, which isn't necessarily the same as insertion order. Thus LinkedHashMap won't necessarily work. I've edited the question to clarify this.

Comment: *It is unfortunately not an option to rewrite the parts that rely on the Java 7 version of the HashMap.* I assume they're using the `Map` interface then? Otherwise you're pretty much stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, your approach is fine. Though everyone seems to have a feeling of inadequacy. However you want to have only implementation changes:

```
Map<Lorem, Ipso> goodMap = new HashMap<>();
HashMap<Foo, Bar> badMap = new HashMap<>();
```

So replace only `new HashMap` with `new Java7HashMap` finding all misfits, and allowing later consolidation, say with better keys using Comparable.

You probably need just to `implement Map` of java 8, and actually I would not even care about missing java 8 support, as it will be working as it did, and a further development *should* offer a replacement of Java7HashMap. Better invest time in rewrites. *A carrot and stick approach.*

Answer (score 8):

The problem is not the `HashMap`, the problem is the code who is using `HashMap` wrong! HashMap gives no garantuee for the order.

Correct the code who is using `HashMap` wrong! This makes the code compatible to later releases of the JDK too.

Comment: I lied here. It's possible, I can't go into much details here, but it would require a script to be built and to run 24/7 for over 2 months to make all historic data compatible with the Java 8 implementation. I came up with this way, and it was considered a possible solution to this problem.